# Access custom array in wordpress using SQL query pHp

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am 100% new to SQL Queries and I have followed the basic tutorial to create one. What I am trying to do is pretty basic, but I just want to clarify a few things (since the tutorial didn't cover it).

First of all, am I on the right path? I want: all variables from `wp_learnpress_section_items` that have the variable `item_type = "lp_lesson`. I don't really care if it's grouped or not but I figured it'd be easier for the next part.

If this is correct on how a query is done I have just two questions.

How do I access the variables and how would I put this into my wordpress's `function.php` or is there a different location to put it? I basically want to grab all my Wordpress posts, check them against some of these variables (I use the * to grab them all but one example is `item_id`) and then check them versus another set of variables. I have the logic down pat.

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     wp_learnpress_section_items
WHERE
     item_type = "lp_lesson"
GROUP BY
     section_id
;
```

Comment: No. Wrong path.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for something similar:

```
global $wpdb;
$sections = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT section_item_id, section_id, item_id FROM wp_learnpress_section_items", ARRAY_A );
$items = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT section_course_id, section_id FROM wp_learnpress_sections", ARRAY_A );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [DISTINCT]
       section_id
     , and
     , other
     , columns 
     , I 
     , actually 
     , want
  FROM wp_learnpress_section_items
 WHERE item_type = "lp_lesson";
```

Also see about prepared statements in php